# Closure properties!

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

If $L_{1}$ is a context-free language and $L_{2}$ a regular one,use the closure properties and explain if the language $L_{2}-L_{1}$ is also context-free or not.How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on the order $L_2 - L_1$ where $L_1$ is context-free, then it suffices to consider the special case $L_2=\Sigma^*$ to find an example where the difference of the two languages is not context-free.

If the order is the other way $L_1 - L_2$ then rewriting into $L_1 \cap (\Sigma^* - L_2)$ makes it possible to apply the fact that CFL are closed under intersection with regular languages.

Comment: For the first case,do you mean that $L_{2}-L_{1}=\Sigma^{*}-L_{1}$ is the complement of $L_{1}$ and that's why it is  not contextfree,because contextfree languages are not closed under complement?

Comment: Yes, more precisely it *can* be non-context-free (if you choose the right $L_1$).

Comment: Could we use the language $L_1=\{w| w$ is not of the form$w=xx\}$, so its complement is the language $\{xx|x \epsilon \{0,1\}^{*}\}$ ?

Comment: Of course you can!

Comment: Nice...and can I just use the language,or do I have to prove that it is contextfree?

Comment: This I cannot answer. This depends on the context where you need it, and what is the knowledge you ae allowed to assume. "not $ww$" is not a really simple language, perhaps $a^*b^*c^* - \{a^nb^nc^n \mid \dots \}$ is a simpler example if you have to prove things from scratch.